# Dispersion relation of silicon

Tags: optics, refraction, crystals, dispersion

In the case of dispersion relation of silicon having crystal plane orientation 111; what is the [Sellmeier's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation) for refractive index $n$ of silicon orientation 111 & what it's extinction coefficient $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Google says [here](http://refractiveindex.info/?group=CRYSTALS&material=Si). There is a database for 111 direction too. No Sellmeier equation is given for this case, but there are tabulated values of n and k vs. wavelength, so you could just fit it to get the equation.